# Spring Boot hateoas + swagger +feign client error application start up

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am using **hateoas** with **spring boot microservices** with swagger and feign client.

In one of the microservice, I use swagger and hateoas it is working fine. But in another, I am using feign additionally it is throwing the below error.

I am not able to make out what is wrong. Do we need to do any config changes for feign client. Any help is appreciated.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/hateoas/FeignHalAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RelProvider must not be null!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/hateoas/FeignHalAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RelProvider must not be null!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/hateoas/FeignHalAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RelProvider must not be null!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1290) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1925) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider.ifAvailable(ObjectProvider.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.configureMessageConverters(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:204) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.configureMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:137) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.configureMessageConverters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:809) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:615) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:371) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/hateoas/FeignHalAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RelProvider must not be null!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/hateoas/FeignHalAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RelProvider must not be null!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1515) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1472) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1316) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.resolveStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1974) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1968) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.messageConverters(HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.java:68) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'halJacksonHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RelProvider must not be null!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RelProvider must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalHandlerInstantiator.<init>(Jackson2HalModule.java:745) ~[spring-hateoas-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar:1.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalHandlerInstantiator.<init>(Jackson2HalModule.java:738) ~[spring-hateoas-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar:1.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalHandlerInstantiator.<init>(Jackson2HalModule.java:722) ~[spring-hateoas-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar:1.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.hateoas.FeignHalAutoConfiguration.halJacksonHttpMessageConverter(FeignHalAutoConfiguration.java:80) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

Comment: With your minimal stack trace, I can see  for message convertor bean  some provider value is injected as null. Refer this bean of yours halJacksonHttpMessageConverter and correct it

Comment: @Karthik I have updated the stack trace and description. If I removed the feign related code it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bean instantiation getting failed because RelProvider is not set for the message converter bean.

Try to follow this link, it has some samples for you to check.

[Spring Hateoas Configuration](https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule)

Comment: Thanks. I will check this.

Comment: Sure TheNightswatch if it helps please accept the answer.

Comment: I was not able to figure this out. I am thinking of a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue when using Spring Boot 2.3.3, Spring HATEOAS 1.1.0 and Spring Cloud OpenFeign 2.2.5.

Because that `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration` only support WebMvc(servlet), but i use WebFlux(reactive).

So, I wrote a autoconfigure myself.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnWebApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HateoasProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaHttpMessageConverterConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverers;
import org.springframework.hateoas.config.EnableHypermediaSupport;
import org.springframework.plugin.core.Plugin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter;

/**
 * {@link EnableAutoConfiguration Auto-configuration} for Spring HATEOAS's
 * {@link EnableHypermediaSupport @EnableHypermediaSupport} when the application is a
 * reactive-based web application.
 *
 * @author Pengxuan Men
 * @since 1.1.0
 */
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnClass({ EntityModel.class, RequestMapping.class, RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class, Plugin.class })
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
@AutoConfigureAfter({ WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, JacksonAutoConfiguration.class,
        HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class, RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        HypermediaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HateoasProperties.class)
@Import(HypermediaHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class)
public class ReactiveWebHypermediaAutoConfiguration {

    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(LinkDiscoverers.class)
    @ConditionalOnClass(ObjectMapper.class)
    @EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
    protected static class ReactiveWebHypermediaConfiguration {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

we have to tell our Spring Boot client application to configure its JSON parsers to use Spring HATEOAS. This can be done by simply annotating your Application class with the @EnableHypermedia

For example

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class DemoApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.